# How to display text of category, has-one belongs to associaton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok i have two models:

```
class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :category_id, :content, :date, :patient_id
has_one :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :text
has_many :treatments
end
```

In my application i tried now to display the text of the category instead of the id for each treatment. Among others i tried this:

```
<% @treatments.each do |f| %>
<%= f.content %>
<%= f.date %>
<%= f.category.try(:text) %>
<% end %>
```

But i get the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: categories.treatment_id
```

So how can i get the text of the category instead of the id? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though you've got an issue with your model relationships. If you're after a standard one-to-many relationship then you need to change

```
has_one :category
```

to

```
belongs_to :category
```

in your Treatment model.